# shdoc and KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script

Why does the following example work with `report`, but not with `scrreprt`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{shdoc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sh}
        \begin{shbox}
            \shline{}{Test}
        \end{shbox}
    \end{sh}
\end{document}
```

Fun fact: I have a class based on `scrreprt` which compiles this example (really works), but there is a printed out "none" before the box.

Comment: I hve a version of `shdoc` from 2015 on my machine, which does some cray stuff, i.e. using its own commands before they are defiend. Something like that should not happen.

Comment: @Johannes_B Version 2016/09/04 v2.1b seems to have solved these but still has other issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the package `shdoc`. It uses

```
\ifthenelse{\f@size<6}{%
```

This is an integer comparison but `\f@size` isn't an integer always. You get the same error with the standard classes, if you use option `11pt`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{shdoc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sh}
        \begin{shbox}
            \shline{}{Test}
        \end{shbox}
    \end{sh}
\end{document}
```

There are other comparisons like this. And also there are comparisons like

```
\ifnum\value{shlinenumber}<10%
```

which are at least dangerous. Here the scanning of number 10 should be terminated, e.g. using `\relax`.

There are also some missing `%` after `{` and some not needed `%` after macros at line ends I do not like. But maybe they aren't problems. I even found an empty line in `\shread`. But I'm not sure whether or not this is an intended paragraph or not.

You should report the bugs.