# How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, verbatim

While trying to implement an own working alternative to `shdoc` (one of its issues see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361275/124577)) I encountered an interesting behaviour of LuaLaTeX I cannot explain.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{luacode}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\terminaloutput}{+v}{
    \directlua{tex.print("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")}
}

\begin{document}
\terminaloutput{
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
}
\end{document}
```

I just defined a function using a verbatim argument (`\terminaloutput`) which has to be verbatim since there is a `_` in `.bash_history`. My question is why LaTeX is able to print the whole content of `#1` (as expected in a continuous way) and Lua doesn't print anything.

Comment: I get no output at all with LuaLaTeX

Comment: @egreg Deleted aux files and you're right. But do you get the full output if using `#1` instead of the `\directlua` line?

Comment: Yes, without line breaks as expected

Comment: @egreg I adapted the question. Primarily I search for the reason for the different behavior.

Comment: An obvious problem is `..` that Lua interprets in the wrong way as far as TeXing is concerned.

Comment: you are not using the luacode package at all here, apart from the fact that you are using the old name `\luatexluaescapestring` you could use `\luaescapestring` with no additional package.

Comment: Cross link to similar question: [luatex - In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/in-lualatex-how-do-i-pass-the-content-of-an-environment-to-lua-verbatim)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, I prefer to refer to and build on Paul Isambert's wonderful article [LuaTEX: What it takes to make a paragraph](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf), published in 2011 in Volume 32 of TUGBoat.

In this article, the author discusses *inter alia* how one can make use of the LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback to handle verbatim material in a very robust and flexible manner. To quote from the article:

> One of the most arcane areas of
> TeX is catcode management. This becomes most
> important when one wants to print verbatim text,
> i.e. code that TeX should read as characters to
> be typeset only, with no special characters, and
> things turn definitely dirty when one wants to
> typeset a piece of code and execute it too (one
> generally has to use an external file). With the
> `process_input_buffer` callback, those limitations
> vanish: the lines we would normally pass to TeX
> can be stored and used in various ways afterward.

The MWE shown below adapts Paul's TUGBoat article code to LaTeX coding practices. (Paul's code is distinctly PlainTEX-ish.) If you're at all interested in this issue, you should absolutely read Paul's original article; the passage on handling verbatim material is on pages 2 and 3 of the pdf file version of the article (pp. 69 and 70 in original published journal volume). Paul explains the issues far better than I possibly could.

- The Lua-side code consists of defining a Lua table (which will hold the verbatim material) and 3 Lua functions that do most of the work.
- The TeX-side code sets up several TeX macros that activate, invoke, and suspend the operation of the Lua functions. The main LaTeX macros are `\printverbatim` (you should be able to guess what it does...) and `\useverbatim`; the latter executes whatever is in the most recently read verbatim chunk.
- A verbatim chunk is anything sandwiched between lines that say `\Verbatim` and `\EndVerbatim`, respectively. If there's any material on the lines that contain the strings `\Verbatim` and `\EndVerbatim`, respectively, it will be ignored.

Note that I have *not* defined a LaTeX environment called `Verbatim`, although it wouldn't be too hard to do so.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%% Set up a Lua table and 3 Lua functions
\directlua{%
```

```lua
verb_table = {}
function store_lines (str)
   if string.find (str , "\noexpand\\EndVerbatim" ) then
      luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
         "process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
   else
      table.insert(verb_table, str)
   end
   return ""
end
function register_verbatim ()
   verb_table = {}
   luatexbase.add_to_callback(
      "process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end
function print_lines ( catcode )
   if catcode then
      tex.print ( catcode , verb_table)
   else
      tex.print ( verb_table )
   end
end
```

```tex
}
%% TeX-side code: define several macros
\def\Verbatim{\directlua{register_verbatim()}}
\def\useverbatim{\directlua{print_lines()}}
\def\printverbatim{%
   \par
   \bgroup
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \ttfamily
   \directlua{print_lines(1)}
   \egroup
   }
\def\createcatcodes{%
   \bgroup
   \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12
   \catcode`\$=12 \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\^^M=13
   \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\_=12
   \catcode`\ =13 \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\%=12
   \savecatcodetable 1 % '\savecatcodetable' is a LuaTeX primitive
   \egroup}
\createcatcodes
\def\Space{ }
\bgroup
\catcode`\^^M=13\gdef^^M{\quitvmode\par}%
\catcode`\ = 13\gdef {\quitvmode\Space}%
\egroup

\begin{document}

\Verbatim
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\EndVerbatim
\printverbatim

\bigskip
\Verbatim
\def\lululu{%
Lua\kern-.01em
\TeX
}%
\EndVerbatim
\printverbatim

\bigskip
\useverbatim % this "registers" the macro "\lululu"
\noindent\lululu
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but is it possible to wrap that into one macro so that the `\Verbatim` and `\EndVerbatim` could be in one call like the `\terminaloutput` in my original code example?

Comment: @TeXnician - The main issue here is that one has to provide the software something specific and unmistakable to "look for" as the terminator of the verbatim material. (In the answer given above, the terminating marker is the string `\EndVerbatim`.) Since verbatim material can consist of fairly arbitrary material, including instances of unmatched `{` and `}`, "counting" the instances of `{` and `}` and looking for the instance of "`}`" that "corresponds to" or "matches" the "`{`" in `\terminaloutput{` won't do. By the way, that's one of the shortcomings of your idea for `\terminaloutput{...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will rethink the concept of my output lines. But for longer outputs an environment (or similar concept like above) is a better option either way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: There are well-debugged and reliable packages, such as `fancyvrb`, out there which work well with both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Is there something the `fancyvrb` package doesn't do for you?

Comment: That was not the point. Just for the logic of writing (and documenting in my case) I really like the idea of `shdoc`. But as mentioned in my OP I already had some issues with it, because of very bad code. So I decided to write an own version replicating the main behavior and using `tcolorbox` (which is far more flexible than what `shdoc` is able to provide).

Comment: @TeXnician - Maybe my answer was focused too much on the specific aspect of handling verbatim material and not enough on some of the other services provided by `shdoc`. Feel free to post a new query, in which you could ask more specific help with other routines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56452/discussion-between-texnician-and-mico).

Comment: @TeXnician - Maybe post a new query focused just on how to "print" the buffer immediately/automatically upon finishing a verbatim block?

Comment: I'll do that within the next days.

Comment: is it possible to do the same but without using lua `table` but using lua string to store the strings being passed in from Tex to Lua?  I tried to do it, but the newline was lost in the process.  I prefer to work with strings concatenation directly instead of lua table {}.  But could not make it work. It will be nice to see how to make your code work using strings instead of table() if possible.

Comment: @Nasser - I think the answer to your general question is "likely, yes". However, without any further information about your document setup, it's unfortunately not possible to say something more specific. Hence, do please post a new query to state what you're trying to achieve. Stating what you've tried so far would also be very helpful.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will make separate question. I am basically trying to implement what you did, but instead of using table {} like you did, use string. I will make separate question soon.

Answer (score 9):

Mico's answer is very good and shows how a low-level implementation of verbatim buffers in LuaTeX could look like.

ConTeXt comes with this feature included and it is super easy to use.

```
\starttext

\startbuffer[terminal]
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\stopbuffer

\typebuffer[terminal]

\startbuffer[logo]
\def\lululu{%
Lua\kern-.01em
\TeX
}%
\stopbuffer

\typebuffer[logo]

\getbuffer[logo]
\lululu

\stoptext
```

The output is similar to Mico's answer.

Comment: Although I do not use Context it is nice to know.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative, that tries to imitate ConTeXt *buffers* is the `scontents` package. The output obtained is the same as in Mico's response, of course it is not *"bullet proof"*, but, allow me to customize the `verbatim` output using `fancyvrb` and `tcolorbox` as I read in your comments.

The main function of the package is to store content, but try to imitate `\typebuffer` using `verbatim`, anyway, here's my answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{default}
% stored in terminal
\begin{scontents}[store-env=terminal]
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\end{scontents}
\typestored[1]{terminal}

% stored in logo
\begin{scontents}[store-env=logo]
\def\lululu{
Lua\kern-.01em
\TeX
}
\end{scontents}
\typestored[1]{logo}
\getstored[1]{logo}
\lululu
\end{document}
```

[image: output-default]

Customizing the output of `\typestored`using `fancyvrb` and `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\makeatletter
\let\verbatimsc\@undefined
\let\endverbatimsc\@undefined
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyvrb,tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{verbatimsc} %
{\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!25, boxsep=0pt, arc=0pt, boxrule=0pt]
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]} %
{\end{Verbatim} %
\end{tcolorbox}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{Using tcolorbox and fancyvrb}
% stored in terminal
\begin{scontents}[store-env=terminal]
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\end{scontents}
\typestored[1]{terminal}

% stored in logo
\begin{scontents}[store-env=logo]
\def\lululu{
Lua\kern-.01em
\TeX
}
\end{scontents}
\typestored[1]{logo}
\getstored[1]{logo}
\lululu

\end{document}
```

[image: output-custom]