# How to print a verbatim block at its end automatically in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, verbatim, lua

This is a follow-up question to [this answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361759/124577). I try to adjust his Lua code to my needs and line numbering already works.

Actually there is one real usability issue and that's my question: How can I print the buffer at `\tdendlongoutput` or the removal from callback respectively? Currently I need an extra command for that.

Here's what I tried so far:

- Inserting the directive right below the callback removal,
- Using `tex.print` to print a LaTeX macro that uses runs that function.

MWE:

```
%!TeX TS-program=lualatex+shellescape
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\directlua{%
verb_table = {}
i = 1
function store_lines (str)
    if string.find (str , "\noexpand\\tdendlongoutput" ) then
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback ("process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
    else
        table.insert(verb_table, tostring(i) .. " " .. str)
        i = i + 1
    end
    return ""
end
function register_verbatim ()
    verb_table = {}
    i = 1
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end
function print_lines ( catcode )
    if catcode then
        tex.print ( catcode , verb_table)
    else
        tex.print ( verb_table )
    end
end
}
\def\tdlongoutput{\directlua{register_verbatim()}}
\def\tduseoutputastex{\directlua{print_lines()}}
\def\createcatcodes{%
    \bgroup%
        \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12%
        \catcode`\$=12 \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\^^M=13%
        \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\_=12%
        \catcode`\ =13 \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\%=12%
        \savecatcodetable 1%
    \egroup%
}
\createcatcodes
\bgroup%
    \catcode`\^^M=13\gdef^^M{\quitvmode\par}%
    \catcode`\ = 13\gdef {\quitvmode\Space}%
\egroup%
\def\Space{ }

\begin{document}\ttfamily
        \tdlongoutput
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users   16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users    4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users    4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users    2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\tdendlongoutput
        \directlua{print_lines(1)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I've modified my original answer in order to restore functioning of the OP's macro `\tduseoutputastex`.)

You may achieve your objective of automatically printing the contents of the verbatim block -- which is understood to be sandwiched between lines that say `\tdlongoutput` and `\tdendlongoutput`, resp. -- as follows: in the Lua function `store_lines`, upon reaching a line that says `\tdendlongoutput`, return the string `\tdlongoutputprint` rather than just a blank line. The macro `\tdlongoutputprint` is defined to print out the contents of the verbatiim buffer.

Note that I've also changed your Lua code as follows: the line numbers of the verbatim material are no longer stored with the verbatim material itself. Instead, they are inserted dynamically at print time, i.e., during the operation of `\tdlongoutputprint`.

If you want to simply store the verbatim block *without* printing out its contents automatically, you should terminate the verbatim block with the `\tdendlongoutputnoprint` instead of `\tdendlongoutput`.

[image]

```
%!TeX TS-program=lualatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
verb_table = {}
i = 1
function store_lines (str)
    if str:find ( "\\tdendlongoutputnoprint" ) then
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback ("process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
        return ""
    elseif str:find ( "\\tdendlongoutput" ) then
        luatexbase.remove_from_callback ("process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
        return ( "\\tdlongoutputprint" )
    else
        table.insert ( verb_table , str )
        return ""
    end
end
function register_verbatim ()
    verb_table = {}
    i = 1
    luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end
function print_lines ( catcode )
    if catcode then
        for i = 1 , #verb_table do
            tex.print ( catcode , i.." "..verb_table[i])
        end
    else
        tex.print ( verb_table )
    end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\def\tdlongoutput{\directlua{register_verbatim()}}
\newcommand\tdlongoutputprint{%
  \bgroup
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
  \ttfamily
  \directlua{print_lines(1)}
  \egroup}

\def\tduseoutputastex{\directlua{print_lines()}}

\def\createcatcodes{%
    \bgroup%
        \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12%
        \catcode`\$=12 \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\^^M=13%
        \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\_=12%
        \catcode`\ =13 \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\%=12%
        \savecatcodetable 1%
    \egroup%
}
\createcatcodes
\bgroup%
    \catcode`\^^M=13\gdef^^M{\quitvmode\par}%
    \catcode`\ = 13\gdef {\quitvmode\Space}%
\egroup%
\def\Space{ }

\begin{document}
\tdlongoutput % start of verbatim block
total 10244
drwxr-xr-x 47 User Users  16384 Mar 31 18:26 .
dr-xr-xr-x  8 User Users   4096 Jun 27  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 User Users   4096 Dec 23 12:49 .editor
-rw-r--r--  1 User Users   2950 Mar 31 09:01 .bash_history
\tdendlongoutput  %% print contents of verbatim block

\tdlongoutput  % define a macro called "\lululu"
\def\lululu{%
  Lua\kern-.01em
       \LaTeX%
  }
\tdendlongoutputnoprint %% no AUTOMATIC printing of verb. block

\bigskip
\tdlongoutputprint %% print contents of latest verb. block "by hand"

\bigskip
\tduseoutputastex % "register" the macro "\lululu"
\noindent\lululu

\end{document}
```