# verbatim code inside \newcommand definition

Tags: verbatim

All the questions I could find on this subject are about people who want to use `\verb` in the argument passed to a command, or about people who want within a \newcommand to wrap one of the arguments within a `\verb(atim)`.

Instead, I just want to use a `\verbatim` environment within something like a \newcommand.  More specifically, I've tried the following:

```
\newcommand \MyFoo {
blabla
\begin{verbatim}
hihi
\end{verbatim}
}
```

and as you probably all know, this doesn't work: the definition goes through, but when I try to use `\MyFoo` I get an error about `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.`).

Strictly speaking, I don't need to use `\newcommand`.  What I have is a bunch of chunks (which contain plain normal text, as well as verbatim elements) stored in a file, and then I want to construct various documents from this by selecting various of those chunks: in one document I might want to use chunk 4, 7, and 9, while in another I might want 4, 6, 7, and 8.

The only solution I could find so far is to store each chunk in a separate file (so I just `\input` the relevant chunk instead of calling a command containing the chunk), but editing hundreds of small files is much too inconvenient, so I'd much rather keep all the chunks in a single file.

I'm thinking of writing a script which extracts the relevant chunks, but I'm still hoping there's a more direct solution.  Now that I think about it, I could also live with someway to set the list of enabled chunks somewhere, then `\input` the chunks-file and within that file have each chunk be conditionalized on its inclusion in the list of enabled chunks.

Comment: Verbatim invocations are not allowed as part of a macro definition.  However, depending on your need, perhaps `\detokenize` would suffice, or even `\texttt` in some cases.

Comment: I assume you're using pdfLaTeX at present to compile your LaTeX documents. Is this assumption correct? Are you free to use LuaLaTeX? If so, the postings [How to print a verbatim block at its end automatically in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362024/5001) and [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I do use `\texttt` at many places, but for multiline code samples, this is impractical.  @Mico: yes, I'm using pdflatex.  I'll take a look at your lualatex links, tank you.

Comment: I think you need to provide a small coded example of what you are trying to do, as it still is a bit vague by your description.

Comment: Of course, for something this simple one could use \texttt{hihi}

Comment: This question is a special case of [listings - How to define macro that only makes argument substitution? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/how-to-define-macro-that-only-makes-argument-substitution/622711#622711) where the content being expanded to by the macro is fixed (therefore `savebox` is possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\MyFooA
\begin{lrbox}{\MyFooA}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 blabla
\begin{verbatim}
hihi
\some \command
& % in verbatim
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\newsavebox\MyFooB
\begin{lrbox}{\MyFooB}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 a second
\begin{verbatim}
in classic \TeX you 
would run out of boxes
but have ~32 thousand these days
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{center}
\usebox{\MyFooB}  
\end{center}


and

\begin{center}
\usebox{\MyFooA}  
\end{center}

and B again

\begin{center}
\usebox{\MyFooB}  
\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Comment: The \subsection commands work a bit weirdly in such lrboxes, but I think I can live with it.  Thanks a lot!