# Defining Commands with \verb||

Tags: verbatim

Is there any way to define some custom command using the `\verb||` environment? As an example, I want to write `{\color{SteelBlue4} \verb|my_data.txt|}` since using the `_` will cause an error if I only use `\texttt{}`. So I tried writing `\newcommand{\Rcode}[1]{{\color{SteelBlue4} \verb|#1|}}`, but this does not work. Is there any way to do this, or is it just not possible?

Comment: See this [TeX FAQ entry](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin) for an explanation on why this doesn't work. For your simple use case you could define `\newcommand\Rcode{\lstinline[basicstyle=\color{...}]}` using the `listings` package.

Comment: You could use `\texttt` and `\_’.

Comment: Did you consider the package `newberbs`?

Comment: Mostly duplicate [verbatim code inside \newcommand definition - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402306/verbatim-code-inside-newcommand-definition), but in this *special case* there's a solution of `newverbs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `\verb` is that it processes its input in a special way that prevents it from appearing inside of other commands or inside command arguments.  For example, these two will give you an error

```
\newcommand\x{\verb|x|} % will only error once \x is used
\section{\verb|x|}
```

However, the command `\verb` itself is allowed to appear inside another command.  This example is legal:

```
\newcommand\x{y: \verb}
\x|y|
```

That is because the argument of `\verb` does *not* appear inside of another command.  Together with the knowledge that the font of `\verb` is determined by `\verbatim@font`, we can patch the `\verb` macro such that is accepts an optional argument and appends it to the font settings.  With this we can then define the requested `\Rcode` command in the same manner.  We pass the optional argument to `\verb` but the other argument we leave out and let `\verb` scan ahead by itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\let\normalverb=\verb
\let\normalverbatim@font=\verbatim@font

\renewcommand*\verb[1][]{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\verbatim@font\expandafter{\normalverbatim@font#1}%
    \normalverb
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\Rcode}{\verb[\color{SteelBlue4}]}

\begin{document}

\Rcode|my_data|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for `newverbs`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\newverbcommand{\Rcode}{\color{SteelBlue4}}{}

\begin{document}

Standard \verb+\verb+: \verb+my_data.txt+ and text after

With \verb+\Rcode+: \Rcode+my_data.txt+ and text after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: this answer is similar to my other answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638992/250119  except that the code is tailored to this specific question</sub>

Using Ulrich Diez's `\DefineVerbatimToScantokens` macro from the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629173/250119 (note. go to that answer to read on how to use that macro & maybe upvote if you find the answer useful. <sub>Unfortunately as far as I know it's not in any package at the moment so you have to copy paste the code</sub>), we can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

%=== Code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens ========================
% ... <copy the code from that answer>
%=== End of code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens =================

\DefineVerbatimToScantokens{\Rcode}{v}{\color{SteelBlue4} \verb|#1|}

\begin{document}


\Rcode|my_data|

\Rcode|!?%\$^+|

\end{document}
```

Also read documentation of xparse.pdf to see what does it mean to specify `v` here and that it allows `%` etc. <sub>[except literal TAB](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508001/keyboard-tab-character-in-argument-v-xparse)</sub> to be included in the argument.