# \verb in \href with $ and | symbol

Tags: verbatim, href

I have a pattern as follows

```
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\verb|stackexchange.com $1|}

\verb|stackexchange.com $1|
```

the generated pdf is:

[image: generated pdf]

what I want is `stackexchange.com $1`. So what can I do?

Escape character `\$` is obviously a solution, but I just want plain text so there is no need to add escape character when I use \newcommand for this pattern, like:

`\newcommand{\tex}[2]{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/#2}{#1}}`

and use it in the following way:

```
\tex{\verb|stackexchange.com $1|}{test}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629134/whats-the-alternative-for-the-standard-verbatim-environment-that-can-be-used-in may be related.

Comment: You are at stake here: you can rather easily define a `\verbhref` command that absorbs the second argument verbatim, but then you need to escape special characters in the URL. The `\href` command works hard to be able to absorb the first argument without the need to escape special characters. Do you expect such URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a working instance of the command `\verb` into `\href`'s 2nd argument can be done **by having stuff that goes into `\href`'s 2nd argument read from .tex-input-file and tokenized under verbatim-category-code-régime** and "then fed" to `\scantokens` under usual category-code-régime for re-tokenization as usual.

For retokenizing under usual category-code-régime you might like to have a `%` at the end of the line which then gets interpreted as a comment-character that prevents `\scantokens`' last inserted endline-character from being effective.

Instead of `\tex` the command is called `\MyMacro` in the following.

**`\MyMacro` relies on its arguments being read and tokenized while verbatim-catcode-régime is in effect.**

Therefore `\MyMacro` works out

- when obtaining the tokens that form these arguments by reading and tokenizing from .tex-input-file.
- when the tokens forming these arguments at some other moment were read and tokenized while verbatim-category-code-régime was in effect before passing them on to `\MyMacro`.

Therefore `\MyMacro` in many situations does not work out if the tokens forming its argument were read and tokenized under a category-code-régime differing from verbatim-category-code-régime, e.g., under usual category-code-régime.
E.g., `\section{\MyMacro{\verb|stackexchange.com $1|}{test}}` does not work out because the tokens forming the arguments of `\MyMacro` were tokenized under usual category-code-régime (instead of verbatim-category-code-régime) when the argument of `\section` was read from the .tex-file and tokenized.
Usage of `\MyMacro` within moving arguments or pdf-strings is generally a big problem.
(A "moving argument" in TeX-jargon is a macro argument which can wind up automatically in many places in the document. E.g., arguments of sectioning-commands like `\chapter` and `\section` are moving arguments because they can make it into the table of contents, into `\nameref`-cross-references, into page-headers, into pdf-bookmarks,...
A pdf-string, e.g., the text of a bookmark within the .pdf-file, is a component of the "infrastructure" of the .pdf-file itself and needs to be encoded in a way which complies to pdf-standards and thus can be understood by programs for viewing and/or otherwise processing .pdf-files.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begingroup
\catcode`\Z=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 Z
\csname @firstofone\endcsname{Z
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\scantokenswithoutendline[1]{\begingroup\newlinechar=-1 \escapechar=92 \scantokens{\endgroup#1%}}Z
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{vv}{%
  \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/#2}{\scantokenswithoutendline{#1}}%
}%

\begin{document}

% This creates a link to the not-existing page
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/test .
% The phrase of the link is:  \verb|stackexchange.com $1|

\MyMacro{\verb|stackexchange.com $1|}{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't understand the code you show because there are some commands I have not learned or used yet, like `scantokenswithoutendline`, `\catcode`, `\csname`. But I have solved my problem. I guess they are commands to interpret the `\verb` code using verbatim-catcode-régime. Thanks very much!