# How to align multiple aligned env. containing \verb?

Tags: align, verbatim

I need to align several R-syntax formulas as equations.

I have a following code:

```
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
&\verb!tActKT  ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)!\\
&\verb!          + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)!\\
&\verb!          + I(1/nprocs):poly(nDOF, 2, raw=T)!
\end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
&\verb!tActDir ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)!\\
&\verb!          + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)!
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

But it's giving me following error:

```
LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.
```

Do you know, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Generally `\verb` cannot be used inside other macros. The way `align/aligned` gathers up its contents probably does not allow the use of `\verb` in this context. What exactly are you trying to do here? Why should these be numbered as math?

Comment: @daleif Because I'm listing many pretty large models, which can be written down using R-syntax, like here. Without it, those equations would be extremely long and hard to read.

Comment: "Normal" LaTeX verbatim-material is not permitted inside other macros. However, this restriction can be eased if you're willing to switch to LuaLaTeX. Have you taken a look at the posting [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001)? One of the answers describes how to use LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback to read in and play back verbatim material.

Comment: I would still never write stuff like this in math mode, but rather as numbered listings using the `listings` package.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, you can put `\verb` inside a `\hbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newsavebox{\boxA}
\newsavebox{\boxB}
\newsavebox{\boxC}
\newsavebox{\boxD}
\newsavebox{\boxE}
\begin{document}
\setbox\boxA=\hbox{\verb!tActKT  ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)!}%
\setbox\boxB=\hbox{\verb!          + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)!}%
\setbox\boxC=\hbox{\verb!          + I(1/nprocs):poly(nDOF, 2, raw=T)!}%
\setbox\boxD=\hbox{\verb!tActDir ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)!}%
\setbox\boxE=\hbox{\verb!          + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)!}%
% you must define the saveboxes OUTSIDE the math environment
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
&\usebox\boxA \\
&\usebox\boxB \\
&\usebox\boxC
\end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
&\usebox\boxD \\
&\usebox\boxE
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

One can simplify this a bit using lstlisting, but at the cost of making every line in a block the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\newsavebox{\boxA}
\newsavebox{\boxB}
\begin{document}
\setbox\boxA=\hbox{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily]
tActKT  ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T) 
          + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)
          + I(1/nprocs):poly(nDOF, 2, raw=T)
\end{lstlisting}}
\setbox\boxB=\hbox{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily]
tActDir ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)
          + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)
\end{lstlisting}}
% you must define the saveboxes OUTSIDE the math environment
\begin{align}
&\usebox\boxA \\
&\usebox\boxB
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: listings demo]

Answer (score 1):

This supports nine lines in the same `align` (extendable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{verbalign}
  {\setcounter{verbalign}{0}}
  {\finishverbalign}

\newcounter{verbalign}
\newtoks\verbaligntoks

\newenvironment{verbline}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment\stepcounter{verbalign}%
   \begin{lrbox}{0}\begin{BVerbatim}}
  {\end{BVerbatim}\end{lrbox}%
   \global\expandafter\setbox\csname verbalignbox\theverbalign\endcsname=\box0 }

\newcommand{\finishverbalign}{%
  \verbaligntoks={%
    &\vcenter{\copy\csname verbalignbox1\endcsname}%
  }%
  \count255=1
  \loop\ifnum\count255<\value{verbalign}%
    \advance\count255 by 1
    \expandafter\addtoverbaligntoks\expandafter{\the\count255}%
  \repeat
  \begin{align}\the\verbaligntoks\end{align}
}

\newcommand{\addtoverbaligntoks}[1]{%
  \verbaligntoks=\expandafter{%
    \the\verbaligntoks\\%
    &\vcenter{\copy\csname verbalignbox#1\endcsname}%
  }%
}

\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox1\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox2\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox3\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox4\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox5\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox6\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox7\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox8\endcsname
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname verbalignbox9\endcsname


\begin{document}

\begin{verbalign}
\begin{verbline}
tActKT  ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)
          + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)
          + I(1/nprocs):poly(nDOF, 2, raw=T)
\end{verbline}
\begin{verbline}
tActDir ~ poly(I(1/nprocs), 3, raw=T) + poly(nDOF, 3, raw=T)
          + poly(ndoms, 3, raw=T)
\end{verbline}
\end{verbalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]