# VerbatimInput gives error when file is too large

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I use `\VerbatimInput` in package `fancyvrb` to wrap my text, which is loaded from external file. But when the external file is too large, it gives the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<argument> ...
```

Is there any solution to increase the file size limit?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: How large is the external file? Second, what are you doing with file at the moment? Third, are you open to a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The file is just about 500 KB, with 200 lines. I want to present a debugging information in pdf, while keeping the format.

Comment: Thanks for these additional pieces of information. (I must confess to feeling a bit baffled about how 200 lines of text can take up 500KB -- unless the lines are really, really long, I suppose.) If you're open to using LuaLaTeX, do take a look at the posting [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001) With Lua(La)TeX, the only meaningful size constraint should be the amount of RAM on your system.

Comment: Maybe you can convert the text file(s) to pdf in the terminal (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf) and then include the pdfs in your LaTeX document?

Comment: Thank you. It works by converting the text files to pdf. I use the following python code http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532908-text-to-pdf-converter-rewrite/

Comment: I tried a 500KB file and got no problem; but 2500 byte long lines could indeed be an issue, but I can't see how you can print such lines on a sheet of paper. Not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the python code http://code.activestate.com/recipes/532908-text-to-pdf-converter-rewrite/ to convert the text to pdf. It works well for large text.