# How to display variable content as verbatim?

Tags: verbatim

I want to create a documentation .pdf that shows examples of code for my commands and also what the result is.

To prevent differences between the description and the result I thought about creating a command to handle that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{m}
{
    #1
    \par
    \begin{verbatim}
        #1
    \end{verbatim}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{O{default}m}
{
    #1: This should be #2
}

\begin{document}
    \example{\myfunction[Nobody]{quite easy}}
\end{document}
```

The problems seems to be the verbatim section since it does not only get the contents of #1 but seems to take whatever is put into the brackets of `\example` until `\end{verbatim}` is found (which never comes)... Is that the case? If so, how to prevent it?

P.S.: Using `\verb|#1|` also did not work...

Comment: you can not use verbatim in the argument of a command (you can not make an egg out of an omelette)

Comment: @DG': Not really. I want it the other way around. I want to expand one variable inside a `\verb` environment not the other way around.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I do not want to use verbatim inside the argument. I want to do the other way around. I want to use the argument as verbatim.

Comment: no you want to put verbatim inside \NewDocumentCommand, so it fails before you consider what to put in the verbatim

Comment: If you're willing and able to compile your document under LuaLaTeX, the query [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001) should be of interest to you. Hint: All limitations with verbatim material inside the arguments of LateX commands can be overcome when using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: But how are the other documentations handling this? I surely can't be the first wanting to solve this problem... Is there another approach?

Comment: grab verbatim (`v` arg type) then use `\scantokens` (or write to a file and read back) to execute

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Doing this is not trivial. Look at the tcolorbox package, it has quite a lot very sophisticated environment s for side-by-side demonstration, see also https://ctan.org/topic/macro-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Ulrike I was able to find a workaround in the package  `tcolorbox` that does exactly what I needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}


\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunction}{O{default}m}
{
    #1: This should be #2
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcblisting}{}
\myfunction[Nobody]{quite easy}
    \end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]