# Print LaTeX3 string verbatim

Tags: verbatim, latex3

I can’t find a way to print the content of a LaTeX3 string and/or a text verbatim (or to be more precise, I found a solution by writing the content to a file and then displaying the verbatim content of that file but it looks really ugly):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printMeVerbatim}{m}{
%% Don’t know what to put here: I managed to write it in a file to write its content verbatim,
%% but it sounds really dirty
#1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

I would like to print this string verbatim: ``\printMeVerbatim{Hello $\delta$.}'' like:
\begin{verbatim}
Hello $\delta$.
\end{verbatim}
ideally using LaTeX3 syntax.

\end{document}
```

Comment: not really a latex3 issue but `ltcmd` (`xparse`) I think you want `v` not `m`

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\printMeVerbatim}{v}{{\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily#1}}` (T1-encoding just in case ... but better use it generally)

Comment: But wait, I actually need to use this in a loop: `\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_robExt_placeholders_seq {- ~ Placeholder ~ called ~ ``##1'' contains:}` where `##1` can contain stuff like underscore. Is there a verbatim equivalent of `\seq_map_inline`?

Comment: See also [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

`v` is provided by `ltcmd` for this sort of use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printMeVerbatim}{v}{%%%%%
%% Don’t know what to put here: I managed to write it in a file to write its content verbatim,
%% but it sounds really dirty
\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
#1%%%%%
\end{flushleft}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

I would like to print this string verbatim: ``\printMeVerbatim{Hello $\delta$.}'' like:
\begin{verbatim}
Hello $\delta$.
\end{verbatim}
ideally using LaTeX3 syntax.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did it as a display like `verbatim` as requested so the quotes are weirdly placed. You coulddo it inline as `\texttt{#1}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but in my actual problem, the string comes from a map: `\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_robExt_placeholders_seq {- ~ Placeholder ~ called ~ ``##1'' contains:}` where `##1` can contain for instance underscores that gets interpreted by latex. Any idea how to proceed in that case?

Comment: @tobiasBora apart from the fact it's almost completely different to your question:-) just use `\detokenize{#1}`  (or `\tl_to_str:n` which is same thing)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (I can only accept it in 5mn)

Comment: I don’t know why, but sometimes my newlines are turned into `\Omega` when printed. I created a new question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694731/why-are-my-newlines-turned-into-omega

Comment: @tobiasBora ah that's a feature... https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1087

Comment: Hum wait… I always want `+v` to parse newline as a newline (it might contain non-LaTeX code, so parsing newline as `\par` would break all my code!)… I only want to display it nicely, so I guess I need to replace `^^J` with newlines before printing the string?

Comment: @tobiasBora but verbatim (for example) makes each end of line `\par` what would you mean by a "newline"? a character 10, as you see, is just a character not a linebreak.

Comment: I want the string to contain the utf-8 code for what people usually denote as `\n` in other programming languages, as it might contain non-latex document (see my usecase in https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1087#issuecomment-1699332910). But I also want to print this string in the pdf, and in that case, when the string contains `\n`, I want to print a latex new line, I guess using `\\`.

Comment: that isn't the way latex or pdf work, a character 10 will not print as a newline

Comment: Ok thanks, but I tried to do `\str_replace_all:Nnn \l_robExt_tmp_str {^^J} { \newline }`, now I literally see the text `\newline` in my pdf… What have I done wrong?

Comment: `_str` variables are like `\string` they just have catcode 12 characters no command names.

Comment: Ok, so using `tl` it works better. I also need to replace spaces: `\tl_set_eq:Nc \l_robExt_tmp_str { l_robExt_placeholder_#2_str } \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_robExt_tmp_str {^^J} { \par } \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_robExt_tmp_str { ~ } { \  }` seems to work fine for now.

Comment: Ok thanks, so using `tl` it seems to work. I also added a special case for spaces (hopefully this is enough for all cases), details in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694776/116348