# Why are my newlines turned into \Omega?

Tags: verbatim, latex3, strings

If I use `^^J` or `\iow_newline:`, it prints a `\Omega` instead of a newline. Any idea what I got wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printTwiceWithNewline}{v}{
  \str_clear_new:N \l_test_str
  \str_gput_right:Nx \l_test_str {\tl_to_str:N{#1}^^J\tl_to_str:N{#1}}
  \str_gput_right:Nx \l_test_str {\iow_newline:\tl_to_str:N{#1}}
  \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
    \l_test_str
  \end{flushleft}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printTwiceWithNewline{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s fully expected.

Comment: @egreg but I'm missing the alpha's at the begin of the lines ;-)

Comment: @egreg ?? How come a newline is expected to be displayed as \Omega?? What if I have the (maybe weird?) will to display newlines as newlines? ^^'

Comment: I’m afraid you’re misunderstanding what `^^J` is for. And this looks very much like an XY-question.

Comment: use `\par` not `^^J`

Comment: If you have `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} ^^J \end{document}` you'd get upper case omega as the output. L3 is not really part of the "problem".

Comment: @egreg So basically this is supposed to be a debug function to write exactly the verbatim content of a latex string in a document. This string might contain any text, including python code etc… So using `\par` instead of `^^J` would likely forbid that file from being compiled in python. So do you suggest I should replace all occurrences of `^^J` with `\\` before printing? If so is there any other characters that might be poorly printed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean I should replace `^^J` with `\par` when printing the string only?

Comment: @tobiasBora it is not clear what is your intention of adding `^^J` above, `^^J` is set up in latex to give a line break in `\typeout` but it is never used anywhere else.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I basically want `\l_test_str` to contain a string with newlines (e.g. python code) that I should be able to write to some files to compile later. How `\l_test_str` is created does not really matters (here I just manually add `^^J` that should hopefully write a `\n` character in the string, but it might come from different sources). Then, I also want to be able to print in LaTeX the python code that I will run: for this I need to be able to print the newlines in `\l_test_str` as real new lines.

Comment: No that is mistaken: a real character 10 in the pdf will give you an omega, you need to the text to be _printed_ on two lines in the pdf (by using `\par`) so your pdf reader if extracting that as plain text will use `\n` characters. You do _not_ want `\n` characters in the pdf.

Comment: this is what happens with a classic `verbatim` environment: every line is marked by `\par`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address [your needs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694731/why-are-my-newlines-turned-into-omega#comment1724576_694731), basically you want to be able to change `^^J` to `\par` between the two uses. An easy way is to define a temporary stand-in macro for the would-be line break. Redefine it before writing to file, and redefine it before printing in PDF.

Here's a LaTeX2e example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\fakeLF{}
\newcommand\teststring{Test\fakeLF Test\fakeLF Test}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\fakeLF{^^J}
\message{\teststring}

\renewcommand\fakeLF{\par}
\teststring
\end{document}
```

---

For the literal question you asked about Omegas: that is because `^^J` generates the unicode `0x000a` line-feed character, and with the default OT1 font encoding this happens to generate the upper case Omega character. The behavior is different, for example, if you switch to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, but it is not working in my usecase: the string are created via:  `\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_robExt_read_ior {\str_gput_right:Nx \l_robExt_tmp {\tl_to_str:N{##1}\fakeLF }}`, but it seems like `\fakeLF` is replaced with the empty string during the `\str_gput_right` call.

Comment: you need a `tl` not a `str` to hold a `\par` token @tobiasBora

Comment: Yeah… but I wanted to avoid using `tl`, exactly because `str` are more predictable ^^'

Comment: Finally I chose a solution where I use `tl` only when printing as it is easier to do it this way in my code. I also needed to do a special case for spaces, hopefully there are no other edge cases.

Answer (score 4):

(Just to explain what is happening.)

The TeX book explains (p. 45)

> If the character following ^^ has an internal code between 64 and 127, TEX subtracts 64 from the code; if the
> code is between 0 and 63, TEX adds 64.

(See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64848/82917) for an explanation of the double caret notation.)

The uppercase `J` has a character code of 74 (as you can find out by typing `` \number`J ``, or looking into an ASCII table), so by the above rule typing `^^J` is the same as requiring the character in slot 74-64=10 in the actual font. This clearly depends on the current font encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\number`J

OT1: ^^J (same as \char10)

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
T1: ^^J (same as \char10)
\end{document}
```

[image]

The LaTeX kernel does `` \newlinechar`\^^J `` but this has an effect only within `\write`s.

Answer (score 1):

I actually chose the solution of converting to `tl` the string, and replacing `^^J` with `\par`, and spaces to `\` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printTwiceWithNewline}{v}{
  \str_clear_new:N \l_test_str
  \str_gput_right:Nx \l_test_str {\tl_to_str:N{#1}^^J\space\space\space\tl_to_str:N{#1}}
  \str_gput_right:Nx \l_test_str {\iow_newline:\tl_to_str:N{#1}}
  %%% replace
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_robExt_tmp_str \l_test_str
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_robExt_tmp_str {^^J} { \par }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_robExt_tmp_str { ~ } { \  }
  \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
    \l_robExt_tmp_str
  \end{flushleft}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printTwiceWithNewline{Test}

\end{document}
```