# LaTeX3: efficient way to remove spaces in front of a command

Tags: latex3

If I have a LaTeX3 string containing:

```
    def f():
        return 42

    def g():
        return 43
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
def f():
    return 42

def g():
    return 43
```

i.e., remove the maximum number of leading spaces/tab (forgetting about empty lines containing only spaced/tabs, I count TAB and space as the same unit) to make sure that I removed the same number of spaces on every line without removing actual text.

What is the most efficient solution to do that? (ideally in LaTeX3) I was thinking to use regexp like `^[ \t]$` to check if the line contains only spaces, and then to count on each line the number of leading space with another regex like `^[ \t]`, but regexp are so inefficient in LaTeX that it is not really a viable solution.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xsimverb}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g__robExt_read_ior%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{getString}{}{%
  \XSIMfilewritestart*{\jobname-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}%
}{%
  \XSIMfilewritestop%
  \ior_open:Nn \g__robExt_read_ior {\jobname-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}%
  %% Put the file in l__robExt_tmp_contain_file_str
  \str_clear_new:N \l__robExt_tmp_str%
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g__robExt_read_ior {%
    \str_gput_right:Nx \l__robExt_tmp_str {##1^^J}%
  }%
  \str_gset_eq:cN {l__my_string_str} \l__robExt_tmp_str%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\printVerbatimString}{}{%
  % For some reasons, newlines are displayed as \Omega. We need to replace them with \\
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694716/print-latex3-string-verbatim/694717
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l__robExt_tmp_tl \l__my_string_str
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__robExt_tmp_tl {^^J} { \mbox{}\par }%mbox needed to print empty lines
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__robExt_tmp_cl { ~ } { \  }
  \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily%
    \l__robExt_tmp_tl
  \end{flushleft}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{getString}
    def f():
        return 42

    def g():
        return 43
\end{getString}
\noindent Before:
\printVerbatimString

Goal:
\begin{getString}
def f():
    return 42

def g():
    return 43
\end{getString}
\printVerbatimString

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we assume this is read in the normal way? If so, tabs are spaces and it's trivial

Comment: If tabs are too hard to deal with, we can start with spaces only. But in practice I get this string from xsim, by writting it first to a file and reading in latex3 that file (maybe not the more efficient solution, but at least it works, is robust, and is simple). I use it in my robust-externalize library. But I'm very surprised to see that it is trivial, is there a builtin function for that?

Comment: @JosephWright I added a MWE

Comment: Why are you using the suffix `_str` for what *must* be a `_tl`?

Comment: @egreg Why should it be a `_tl`? I want to consider it as a string (i.e. only a sequence of basic letters), and I thought that `\ior_str_map_inline` was always providing str so that `tl_to_str` is not useful?

Comment: if these are strings then why are you using \tl_set_eq:NN on them?

Comment: Just naming a token list with the suffix `_str` doesn't make it into a string. And if you try `\str_show:N \l__robExt_tmp_str` you'll see an error message. And that *token list* contains much more than a simple list of characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use `\tl_set_eq` only in the printing part, my goal being to convert the string to a token list, as this time I want to add tokens like `\par` for new lines etc…

Comment: @egreg oh, do you mean in the printing part or in the `getString` environment? In the printing part this is indeed a typo I made (fixed). On the `getString` however, I would expect this to be a string, what makes it a non-string?

Comment: @tobiasBora How is it fixed? `\tl_set_eq:NN \l__robExt_tmp_tl \l__my_string_str` is wrong ....

Comment: @cfr why? I thought str was a "subset" of tl, so that I can just create a tl from a str using `\tl_set_eq`. I can't find any `\str_to_tl` (white `\tl_to_str` does exist), so I have no idea how to make this correct otherwise.

Comment: @tobiasBora I'm not sure whether `\tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_str` is correct, however, I can guarantee that `\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_str` is correct (though slower).

Comment: You're using global assignments on multiple local variables. Please note that a variable starting with `l` should only be assigned to locally, a global variable should be named with a leading `g` and only be assigned to globally. (`\str_gset_eq:cN` and `\str_gput_right:Nx` are global assignments!)

Comment: The variable `\l__my_string_str` isn't declared, the fact that the first assignment to it is done via `c`-expansion doesn't change that. Same is true for other variables. Please declare variables before using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following does what you want. It might not be the fasted method to do it, but it should be rather straight forward.

I count the leading symbols to strip by counting the spaces in the string before and after removing all leading ones. The space remover simply loops for the minimum count of leading spaces removing one space or tab at a time.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xsimverb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g__robExt_read_ior
\tl_new:N \l__robExt_tmp_tl
\str_new:N \l__robExt_tmp_str
\int_new:N \l__robExt_whitespaces_int
\seq_new:N \l__robExt_lines_seq

\str_new:N \g__my_string_str

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_other:N \^^I
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__robExt_count_leading_whitespace:n #1
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l__robExt_tmp_str {#1}
    \str_replace_all:Nnn \l__robExt_tmp_str { ^^I } { ~ }
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l__robExt_tmp_str
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__robExt_whitespaces_int
          {
            \int_min:nn
              { \l__robExt_whitespaces_int }
              {
                \str_count_spaces:N \l__robExt_tmp_str -
                \str_count_spaces:e
                  { \exp_last_unbraced:NV \use:n \l__robExt_tmp_str {} }
              }
          }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count_spaces:n { e }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:n #1
  {
    \use:e
      {
        \exp_not:n { \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:nN {#1} }
        \prg_replicate:nn
          { \l__robExt_whitespaces_int - 1 }
          { \exp_not:N \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:nN }
      }
    \use:n
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:nN #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nT {#1} \prg_break:
    \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#1}
      { \exp_args:No #2 { \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:w #1 } }
      {
        \tl_if_head_eq_charcode:nNTF {#1} ^^I
          { \exp_args:No #2 { \use_none:n #1 } }
          { \prg_break:n {#1} }
      }
  }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNo \cs_new:Npn \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:w \c_space_tl {}
\group_end:

\NewDocumentEnvironment { getString } {}
  { \XSIMfilewritestart*{\jobname-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp} }
  {
    \XSIMfilewritestop
    \ior_open:Nn \g__robExt_read_ior { \jobname-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp }
    %% Put the file in l__robExt_tmp_contain_file_str
    \seq_clear:N \l__robExt_lines_seq
    \int_set_eq:NN \l__robExt_whitespaces_int \c_max_int
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g__robExt_read_ior
      {
        \__robExt_count_leading_whitespace:n {##1}
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l__robExt_lines_seq {##1}
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT \l__robExt_whitespaces_int > \c_zero_int
      {
        \seq_set_map_e:NNn \l__robExt_lines_seq \l__robExt_lines_seq
          { \__robExt_whitespace_trimmer:n {##1} }
      }
    \str_gset:Nx \g__my_string_str { \seq_use:Nn \l__robExt_lines_seq { ^^J } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \printVerbatimString {}
  {
    % For some reasons, newlines are displayed as \Omega. We need to replace them with \\
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694716/print-latex3-string-verbatim/694717
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l__robExt_tmp_tl \g__my_string_str
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__robExt_tmp_tl {^^J} { \mbox{}\par }%mbox needed to print empty lines
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__robExt_tmp_tl { ~ } { \  }
    \begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
      \l__robExt_tmp_tl
    \end{flushleft}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{getString}
    def f():
        return 42

    def g():
        return 43
\end{getString}
\noindent Before:
\printVerbatimString

Goal:
\begin{getString}
def f():
    return 42

def g():
    return 43
\end{getString}
\printVerbatimString

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Who awesome, thanks a lot! I'm still trying to wrap my head around this solution. First, I'm not sure to understand how you count leading spaces, notably, what is `\exp_last_unbraced:NV \use:n \l__robExt_tmp_str {} ` exactly doing? For the formula to work, I guess it should output the part of the string after the first spaces, but I have to admit I don't see why it works… Also, once you have the number of spaces to trim, why do you need this complex whitespace trimmer? Can't you "just" use `\str_range`?

Comment: @tobiasBora it assumes that the number stored in `\l__robExt_whitespaces_int` might be wrong and does never trim a non-whitespace character, hence the complicated trimmer. Most likely in your use case `\str_range:nnn` is fine and you can use it instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. And what about `\exp_last_unbraced:NV \use:n \l__robExt_tmp_str {}`?

Comment: `\exp_last_unbrace:NV` expands the value `\l__robExt_tmp_str` before `\use:n` runs. Then `\use:n` grabs the first none-space token of the string and reinserts it (because of TeX-rules that an undelimited parameter ignores spaces), the `{}` at the end is used if the string is blank but doesn't change the count of spaces, hence is fine.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Actually, I'm just realizing: you directly plug yourself on `\ior_str_map_inline:Nn` to iterate over the lines of the file, but in practice I do this operation much later (the file has already been converted to a single string). Can I easily & efficiently loop over all lines of a string? (the only guarantee I have is that all of them end with `^^J`) The `str_map` operate character by character and your solution assumes that we can directly parse the whole string (I assume it will also be more efficient if we can directly parse the whole line at once instead of per char).

Comment: `\seq_set_split:Nnn` with `^^J` as separator, then use `\seq_map_...` to count the whitespaces before the `\seq_set_map_e:NNn`, rebuild the string by `\str_set:Ne` with `\seq_use:Nn` with `^^J`.

Comment: Oh good point, I was trying to find this function among the `\str_*` part of the documentation. I'll try that, thanks a lot!

Comment: (actually, I guess I want `\seq_set_split_keep_spaces` to keep the spaces)

Comment: @tobiasBora yes, you want the `keep_spaces` variant, sorry my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autogobble` option in `minted` which does exactly this. `minted` requires `--shell-escape` though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
    def f():
        return 42

    def g():
        return 43
\end{minted}

\bigskip

      
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{python}
    def f():
        return 42

    def g():
        return 43
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I would need to do it without shell escape (I ideally need to compute the hash of the string in pure LaTeX, this is needed for my library robust-externalize)

Comment: @tobiasBora No problem I suspected as much but I thought I'd post anyway as others may land here and minted does have that specific option.